# spectral sequence differential for cobordism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, cobordism, spin-geometry

From page 6 of [these solutions](http://www.dcrowley.net/Budapest2011Solutions.pdf):

> the differential\begin{equation}d_2: H_p(X,\Omega_1^{Spin})\rightarrow H_{p-2}(X,\Omega_2^{Spin})\end{equation}connecting the 1-st and the 2-nd row is the $\textbf{dual}$ of second Steenrod cohomology operation $Sq^2$.

Can someone please explain to me why this is true?

Comment: Warmest welcome to MO

Comment: I would imagine that this is for similar reasons as those given by Tyler Lawson here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62642/third-differential-in-atiyah-hirzebruch-spectral-sequence for why $d_3$ in the AHSS for complex K-theory is the integral $Sq^3$.